# How to avoid `getNotification` deprecated?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I making Alarm app and have below code in MyAlarmService.

```
public class MyAlarmService extends Service
{
    private NotificationManager mManager;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        mManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification.Builder notification = new Notification.Builder(MyAlarmService.this);
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),ReminderPage.class);
        PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this.getApplicationContext(),0, intent1,0);
        notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable. notification_template_icon_bg)
                .setContentTitle("Music player")
                .setContentIntent(pendingNotificationIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification1 = notification.getNotification();
        notificationManager.notify(R.drawable.notification_template_icon_bg, notification1);
        mManager.notify(0, notification1);
        return super.onStartCommand(intent,flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

1. In onStart method,it always has a strikethrough. After googled, I changed `onStart` method to `onStartCommand()`,but not sure is this the correct way to modify.
2. `getNotification` is deprecated.

**AndroidMainfest**

```
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
```

**Thanks.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

can you try this,

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context);
        notification = builder.setContentIntent(intent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.push_icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(when)
                .setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message).build();
        notificationManager.notify(requestID, notification);
```

Comment: should I need  `return super.onStartCommand(intent,flags, startId);` ?

Comment: yes, you can.It simply work just change the few methods

Comment: your last line sir

Comment: wait let me check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124926/discussion-between-saveen-and-ai).

Answer (score 4):

You named the Notification Builder 'notification'.
So you should simply replace notification.getNotification() with notification.build().

That's it. Explained in official doc: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder#getNotification()